# Correlated subqueries vs. immutable functions

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, correlated-subquery

```
create table t1 as
select 100 col1, '{A,B,C}'::character varying[] col2
union all
select 200, '{A,B,C}'::character varying[] 
union all
select 150, '{X,Y,Z}'::character varying[]
union all
select 250, '{X,Y,Z}'::character varying[];

create table t2 as
select 'A' col1, 10 col2
union all
select 'B', 20 
union all
select 'C', 25
union all
select 'X', 15
union all
select 'Y', 10
union all
select 'Z', 20;
```

Consider this query:

```
select t1.col1,
       (select sum(col2)
        from t2
        where t2.col1 = any(t1.col2))
from t1;
```

My understanding is that if I implement that subquery as a function call instead and define that function as `IMMUTABLE`, it will execute twice instead of four times.
Is this also true for the correlated subqueries?

Does the planner evaluate the contents of input arrays for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

It will not cache the results, neither with a function nor with a subquery. Run `EXPLAIN` to convince yourself.

That's why you should use a join rather than a subselect for this kind of request to avoid a nested loop.

Comment: Thanks.
Is this because the subquery caching is not supported or because it doesn't like arrays? The reason I asking is because some optimizers do have this feature.
I am puzzled why the equivalent UDF will not cache results. I thought they are explicitly designed to do that.

Comment: PL/pgSQL functions cache *query plans*, not *query results*.